# What is the equivalent in GCC to MSVC's '#pragma message'?

Tags: c++, gcc, pragma

On MSVC I can issue *compilation-time* message like so:

```
#pragma message("...some compilation-time message...")
```

Is there an equivalent in GCC?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html `#pragma message`, `#pragma GCC warning`.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI that should be posted as an answer instead of a comment

Comment: the difference is not between windows and linux but between the compilers you are using

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI thank you. I thought I was receiving warnings but now I can see it is a 'note'. Also, in gcc brackets are not needed as in Windows. You can post an answer and I will mark it solved. Thank you

Comment: i suppose you are using msvc. You could use gcc also in windows and it uses the same pragma as if you used gcc in linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `#pragma` in gcc too. Otherwise there is warning and error:

```
#pragma message("...some compilation-time message...")
#warning I warn you.
#error I mean it.
```

results in

```
$ g++ -O2 -W -Wall -g -c foo.cc
foo.cc:2:2: warning: #warning I warn you. [-Wcpp]
    2 | #warning I warn you.
      |  ^~~~~~~
foo.cc:3:2: error: #error I mean it.
    3 | #error I mean it.
      |  ^~~~~
foo.cc:1:54: note: ‘#pragma message: ...some compilation-time message...’
    1 | #pragma message("...some compilation-time message...")
      |                                                      ^
```